# Unzip Folder Not moving files to Root Folder

Tags: php, command-line, command

I have the PHP script below.  It installs the files on a server into a subfolder, but it does not move the files to the root destination folder from the subfolder like the command line is asking.  I can't seem to figure out why.

```
echo self::rex($ssh,"mv $args[ipath] $args[ipath]-".time()." >> /root/cms-inst.log"); 
echo self::rex($ssh,"mkdir /tmp/inst-$rt >> /root/cms-inst.log"); 
echo self::rex($ssh,"unzip -oq /tmp/cms-latest-$rt.zip -d /tmp/inst-$rt >> /root/cms-inst.log");
echo self::rex($ssh,"mv /tmp/inst-$rt $args[ipath] >> /root/cms-inst.log");
```

I tried this command

```
echo "INSTALLING APP TO $args[ipath]....\n";
```

Comment: What is `rex`? Might want to tag that library

Comment: And have you checked */root/cms-inst.log* ?

Comment: You're redirecting stdout to a file. I don't know if `self::rex()` displays stderr. If it doesn't, you may want to redirect it to a file as well.